# Does this do while code mean that the input will always be in Float? What does the while do in the end?

Tags: java, while-loop

1. THis is a part of my input
2. I would like the user to input only in float, what does this mean?:

   ```
   Boolean start;
   do{
       System.out.println("Enter value for Alpha:");
           if(sc.hasNextFloat()){
               al = sc.nextFloat();
               start = true;
           } else{ 
               System.out.println("Please enter a number");
               start = false;
               sc.next();
           }
       } while(!(start));
   ```

Comment: At first glance, I'd say you've achieved your goal of requiring the use to input a `float'.  What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code for your problem:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter value for Alpha:");
    while(true) {
        if(sc.hasNextFloat()) {
            float al = sc.nextFloat();
            System.out.println(al);
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Enter a valid float");
            sc.next();
        }
    }
    sc.close();
}
```

Comment: If you don't close `System.in` or (out, err) it will be closed anyone on program exit.

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean start;
start = false;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
float alphaFloat;
do {
   try{
         System.out.println("Enter value for Alpha: ");
         String alpha = sc.next();
               if(alpha.contains(".")) {
                   System.out.println("Float stored");
                    alphaFloat = Float.valueOf(alpha);
                    start = true;
              }
               else {
                     System.out.println("Please enter a float. That was not a float.");

              }

               catch(NumberFormatException e) {
                     System.out.println("Please enter a number that is properly formatted");
         }

               finally {
                      System.out.println("\r\n");
         }

       }while(!start);
```

Here is your sample output:
    Enter value for Alpha: 
    2.2.2.2
    Invalid

```
Enter value for Alpha: 
2
Please enter a float. That was not a float.


Enter value for Alpha: 
3.5
Float stored
```

In your code the user could enter an int technically and it will still execute although you have the hasNextFloat() method within your conditional statement. I edited the code and made the input a String. Therefore, if the String has a decimal within it, we can typecast it to a float. If there is no decimal, We know that it is not a float and will ask for additional input. Now, another factor is that you could typecast any user input to a float if you wanted to. It would probably also be a good idea to set up a try-catch block so that you can handle a user potentially entering an invalid number.